# What is the best way to convert .mp3 file to юogg during its loadind to server?

Tags: javascript, github, audio, compression

Is there any library or something else to converts mp3 file to ogg file during its uploading to the server?

Or may be you know how to compress mp3 file to make it smaller for the server?

Comment: Just so you know, converting from one lossily compressed format to another can introduce artifacts in the audio, since different compressed formats exclude different data when compressing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use ffmpeg for the conversion mp3 to ogg

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp3 -c:a libvorbis -q:a 5 output.ogg
```

Set the output quality by adjusting the value of -q:a:

for this codec the range is 0-10 and higher gives better quality.

Better compression - lower the value more the compression - size of the file is smaller.

ffmpeg javascript plugin are also available :

https://github.com/Kagami/ffmpeg.js/

https://github.com/muaz-khan/Ffmpeg.js/

ffmpeg also has C library interfaces :

please check the API interface for these library of FFMPEG

1. avcodec.lib ([example](https://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/0.6/api-example_8c-source.html))
2. swresample.lib

Comment: As I understood, ffmpeg is an .exe program, but I need a piece of code that can compress or convert .mp3 file durign its loading to server.

Answer (score 1):

Use Gstreamer for the conversion mp3 to ogg

cmdline option:

```
gst-launch-0.10 -v filesrc location=infile.mp3 ! decodebin2 location=infile.mp3 ! audioconvert ! vorbisenc ! oggmux ! filesink location=outfile.ogg
```

you can also call the gstreamer pipleline from your code too.